# U-SQL : how to apply the logarithm function in a query?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I want to query a table an apply the natural logarithm to the field 'sales'.
Is there a way to calculate the natural logarithm for a field in U-SQL? Seems like it is [not being supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/operators/csharp-functions-and-operators#pow) currently.

How can I write a query with a simple in-line call to the function?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found is calling the c# function Math.Log()
`System.Math.Log(sales) AS log_sales`